# Is it haram to use something that was not faithfully obtained?

Tags: halal-haram, lying

When I was 12 years old, my parents have told me that they're going to buy me a MacBook Pro if I didn't cry for computer related issues when they were away. However I did, and I have told my baby sitter and my sister not to tell my parents about it. And now, I no longer use my MacBook Pro and is it haram? Is the online accounts created on that laptop Haram? Should I delete those accounts (inc. my Facebook)?

Comment: Why don't you tell your parents now to forgive you so that you can happily use your laptop?

Comment: @tarek Do I have to delete my online accounts which I have created on that laptop though?

Comment: I don't think you would be hold accountable for your deeds at that age because you were not an adult and would be considered a minor in Islam-- someone to whom the Shariah ruling doesn't apply. I'd not worry about the the laptop and tell my parents what I did (just to pacify my fears or doubts). Allah knows best. Don't worry. He is the most Merciful.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have no problem using your laptop now,

> Do I have to delete my online accounts which I have created on that laptop though?

Let me make a couple of analogies.

If you made an important file with your laptop in the past, do you have to delete it now? I really don't think so.

If you learned a skill with your laptop, should you make yourself forget this skill? Definitely not.

So, I don't think there is any need to undo anything you did in the past with your laptop.

Comment: Don't worry, I have told my dad the truth, as he was the one who bought it.